# ASCII to int to ASCII (ATMEGA 2560)

Tags: c++, c, embedded, uart

I'm trying to make a embedded c project where i will input 7 chars and make some calculations with them - now i got problem getting my conversion to work - I'm working with a ATMEGA 2560, where I output the chars on uart.

Here's the code:

```
volatile char daata[8] = "123:456\0";
volatile char recdata[8];
volatile char data = 0;
volatile char byte;
volatile int minimum;
volatile int maximum;
volatile char mx;
volatile char mi;
```

and my function uses:

```
void putsUSART0(char *ptr)
{
    while(*ptr)
    {
        putchUSART0(*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

and

```
void putchUSART0(char tx)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));   // wait for empty transmit buffer

    UDR0 = tx;
}
```

where the code im working on is:

```
minimum = (100 * (daata[0] - 0x30) + 10 * (daata[1] - 0x30) + daata[2] - 0x30);
maximum = daata[6] - 0x30 + 10 * (daata[5] - 0x30) + 100 * (daata[4]);

mi = minimum + 0x30;
putsUSART0("mimimum is:");
//putchUSART0(minimum );
putsUSART0(mi);
putsUSART0("maximum is:");
putchUSART0(maximum);
_delay_ms(5000);
status = requestsample;
```

The problem is that my output is

> mimimum is:maximum is:ˆ

Can anyone explain the strange behavior.

Comment: You don't say what output you want. I guess you want to format the numeric values as decimal; you might do that using the inverse of the operations you used to read the decimal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char buf[15];
...
mi = minimum + 0x30;
sprintf(buf, "%d", mi);
putsUSART0("mimimum is:");
//putchUSART0(minimum );
putsUSART0(buf);
```

Do similar for maximum also

You are sending the value of ASCII character (and trying to convert it to character by adding `0x30` which is not the right way, you need to convert all digits) and possibly printing it without conversion at the other end.

---

From kind comment of [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin)

> sprintf() is probably not an option, as this is an embedded project,
>   where that function usually is far too slow and memory-consuming.

You can also write your own function that can convert a number to string:

```
const char *numToStr(int n) {
  /* Non-reentrant, returned buffer will be invalidated on subsequent call */
#define BUF_SIZE 15
  static char buf[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
  int pos = BUF_SIZE - 1;
  int neg = 0;
  if(n < 0) {
    neg = 1;
    n *= -1;
  }
  do {
    buf[--pos] = (n % 10) + '0';
    n /= 10;
  } while(n);
  if(neg) buf[--pos] = '-';
  return &buf[pos];
}
```

And use this to convert number to string.

---

From kind comment of [Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)

> Fails for numToStr(INT_MIN) Suggest `if(n < 0) { neg = 1; } else { n =
>   -n; } do { buf[--pos] = '0' - (n % 10); n /= 10; } while(n);`

A version to handle `INT_MIN` can be written as:

```
const char *numToStr(int n) {
  /* Non-reentrant, returned buffer will be invalidated on subsequent call */
#define BUF_SIZE 15
  static char buf[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
  int pos = BUF_SIZE - 1;
  int neg = 0;
  if(n < 0) {
    neg = 1;
  } else {
    n = -n;
  }
  do {
    buf[--pos] = '0' - (n % 10);
    n /= 10;
  } while(n);
  if(neg) buf[--pos] = '-';
  return &buf[pos];
}
```

Comment: sprintf() is probably not an option, as this is an embedded project, where that function usually is far too slow and memory-consuming.

Comment: @Lundin Hmmm, then possibly some function that does the reverse. i.e. set buf[14] to `'\0'` and buf[13...] with successive digits and return the pointer to the most significant digit. I will try to add one such example.

Comment: Perfect - worked like a charm :) but had to remove 0x30 from     mi = minimum + 0x30;

Comment: @Martin And you just blew up 25% or so of the total RAM memory available of your ATmega 2560... Check you map file, then go back to your original code.

Comment: Or indeed roll out your own conversion routine, feel free to use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994742/want-to-convert-integer-to-string-without-itoa-function/10011878#10011878).

Comment: Fails for `numToStr(INT_MIN)`  Suggest `if(n < 0) { neg = 1; } else { n = -n; } do { buf[--pos] = '0' - (n % 10); n /= 10; } while(n);`

Answer (score 0):

`daata[4]` should be `daata[4] - 0x30`. This causes you to get 100*52 instead of 100*4 as intended.

The way to avoid simple bugs like this is some coding discipline: don't put everything on the same line, be consistent and avoid "magic numbers".

```
minimum =   (100 * (data[0] - '0') 
          + ( 10 * (data[1] - '0') 
          + (  1 * (data[2] - '0');

maximum =   (100 * (data[4] - '0'))
          + ( 10 * (data[5] - '0'))
          + (  1 * (data[6] - '0'));
```